# redirect_uri_mismatch Error

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-signin

I have Created the google console Client ID,Client secret by entering the details as per the image attached . But when i click  on google+ login button from my website navigated to gmail login page , after entering the credentials it navigated to redirect_uri_mismatch error page. But the error page showing the uri as http://erudo.in/auth/google/callback .Actually I entered it on google console as https://erudo.in/auth/google/callback .  Why https changed to http ?

Comment: There is no image attached. Also, your login page should specify the `redirect_uri`. And your login page specifies or implies `http://` but you've not allowed this in the console.

Comment: On google console i entered Authorized JavaScript origins as https://erudo.in . And Authorized redirect URIs as https://erudo.in & https://erudo.in/auth/google/callback . But redirect_uri_mismatch error page showing error like this . "The redirect URI in the request, http://erudo.in/auth/google/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client"